# Ruby exception handling: can't suppress NoMethodError

Tags: ruby

I simply want my method call to suppress all "NoMethodError" exceptions that might arise in the methods it in turn calls.

```
def foo
  begin
    bar1
    bar2
  rescue Exception
    return '--'
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work.  NoMethodError keeps being raised to the top level.

The exact error is `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass' (NoMethodError)

Comment: This code works fine for me, even if bar1 and bar2 throw NMEs.  Can you post the code where foo is called?

Comment: exact error is `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass' (NoMethodError)

Comment: Works just fine for me as well.

Comment: @someguy: That's all well and good, but without more of the code we can't do anything with it (other than advise you to stop trying to index into nil).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Object
    def method_missing(meth,*args)
        # do whatever you want here
        end
    end
```

If you want something less global, you can do this on an narrower class, or even a specific instance:

```
class << my_object
    # and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as given works fine.

Extrapolating from your error, I'm guessing what you're actual code is is more like this:

```
class MyClass
  def [](arg)
    self.bim
    self.bam
    self.boom
  rescue Exception
    "--"
  end
end
```

And that later you're trying:

```
obj[ 'whatever' ]
```

And getting `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass' (NoMethodError)`.  This isn't happening b/c you've defined the `MyClass#[]` method incorrectly, it's b/c your `obj` isn't an instance of `MyClass`, it's `nil`.  Probably as a result of an earlier call.